# If $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ is a representation with sub-representation $\tau$, is $\tau^{\otimes n}$ a subrepresenation of $\rho^{\otimes n}$?

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

I'm working over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$ so I'm not assuming that $\tau$ is a direct summand of $\rho$. I think I can prove this by looking at the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the matrices, but does it follow from a more abstract result of representation theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious map $\tau^{\otimes n}\to\rho ^{\otimes n}$.which is injective (because it is the tensor product of several copies of the inclusion $\tau\to\rho$, and the tensor product of injections is an injection because we are tensoring over a field). What you want is an immediate consequence of this.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that.